# Locked Textbox when add value in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP .Net MVC project.
I want to disable a textbox after entering a value. 
How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by locked textbox !

Comment: Lock when a value is entered in a textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Javascript;

```
function Enter() {
    $("#textbox1").prop("disabled", true);}
```

And your Textbox like this;

```
<input type="text" value="test1" onClick="Enter();" id="textbox1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "onfocusout" event. [W3C OnFocusOut Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp)